# DMaaP to Snowflake migration

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to replace DMaaP data router in my OSS architecture with Snowflake. Please suggest how can that be done. I can think of making staging area to unload certain table, not sure if that is the right way.

Comment: [Snowpipe](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe.html) could probably be used in this context.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.